# Get the values passed by ajax to a web service and printing it

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a simple web service where it receives a JSON object from a mobile app and adds that data in to a database. For testing i have created a separate web page that consists of a form and send that data using ajax to my web service.

My problem is i want to check how the data is passed to the web service and since the call is ajax i can't print out the JSON object from the php script. The data is not inserting to the database and i not sure how to debug this.

What can i do to see the JSON objects passed to the web service from that php script? Please help..

Comment: You can use a proxy like charles o intercept all web traffic and view it. In chrome you can use the debugging tools to view the headers passed, firebug also allows that.

Comment: simple, if you are using chrome developer tools ( or whatever browser's dev tool ), open it up, enable logging for ajax requests, inspect the request once it made to the server. You can get all the information related to the request and the response from the server like headers and payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see exactly what you're sending to the web service with Fiddler. Here's a link:
http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

By other hand, if your data isn't inserted into the DB, you should post some code to check it.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to see the JSON object, you can log the object to a file using

```
error_log($_POST['json_object'], 3, "log.txt");
```